# Mysql query with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables. Something like table1 and table2 given below: 
table1 has ID (primary key) and columns Aid, Bid and Cid which are primary key of table 2.

```
table1

ID  Aid Bid Cid
-----------------
1   X   Y   Z
2   X   Z   Z
3   Y   X   X
-----------------

table2

ID  NAME
------------------
X   Abc
Y   Bcd
Z   Cde
------------------
```

I want a query which will fetch all columns from table1 this way (after replacing Aid , Bid and Cid with their corresponding names given in table2):

```
    ID   A   B   C
    1   Abc Bcd Cde
    2   Abc Cde Cde
    3   Bcd Abc Abc
```

Can you please tell me the mysql query to do this.?

Thank you very much for your answers. But am gettin this when I execute those queries :

```
+------+------+------+------+
| ID   | A    | B    | C    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    3 | bcd  | abc  | abc  |
|    1 | abc  | bcd  | cde  |
|    2 | abc  | cde  | cde  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

This query : `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 aa ON table1.Aid = aa.ID JOIN table2 bb ON table1.Bid = bb.ID JOIN table2 cc ON table1.Cid = cc.ID;`

gives this result :

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ID   | Aid  | Bid  | Cid  | ID   | NAME | ID   | NAME | ID   | NAME |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    3 | Y    | X    | X    | Y    | bcd  | X    | abc  | X    | abc  |
|    1 | X    | Y    | Z    | X    | abc  | Y    | bcd  | Z    | cde  |
|    2 | X    | Z    | Z    | X    | abc  | Z    | cde  | Z    | cde  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I think the query needs to be changed a bit..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
select table1.ID, a.NAME AS A, b.NAME AS B, c.NAME AS C
from table1 
join table2 a on table1.Aid = a.ID 
join table2 b on table1.Bid = b.ID 
join table2 c on table1.Cid = c.ID
```

Otherwise:

```
select table1.ID, a.NAME, b.NAME, c.NAME from table1 join (select * from table2) a on table1.Aid = a.ID join (select * from table2) b on table1.Bid = b.ID join (select * from table2) c on table1.Cid = c.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But its giving me a different result. Please see my edit on the question.

Comment: The difference is because you did `select *`, which is not what I did in my answer. Instead, you want to select only certain columns: `select table1.ID, aa.NAME, bb.NAME, cc.NAME`

Comment: Am getting this result 
+------+------+------+------+
| ID   | A    | B    | C    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    3 | bcd  | abc  | abc  |
|    1 | abc  | bcd  | cde  |
|    2 | abc  | cde  | cde  |
+------+------+------+------+
when i execute the queries u said.. without changing..

Comment: I don't see the problem. Is it because the ordering of the rows is random? just tack on `order by table1.ID` to the end.

Comment: u can just add order by in this query it will work.. @Ridhima

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. `INNER JOIN` & `ORDER` -

```
SELECT a.ID, b.NAME, c.NAME, d.NAME
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.ID = a.Aid
INNER JOIN table2 c ON c.ID = a.Bid
INNER JOIN table2 d ON d.ID = a.Aid
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Comment: ohh yes, order by is must required in this.. good one my friend.

Comment: @devpro The answers were also returning the same data with different order. Just missed the proper order. :)

Comment: yes my friend, i have checked this query to, on my dummy db. perfect one, and this person deserve for appreciation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.ID, aa.NAME A, bb.NAME B, cc.NAME C
FROM table1
JOIN table2 aa ON table1.Aid = aa.ID
JOIN table2 bb ON table1.Bid = bb.ID
JOIN table2 cc ON table1.Cid = cc.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But its giving me a different result. Please see my edit on the question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2a.NAME as A, t2b.NAME as B, t2c.NAME as C
from table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2a ON t1.Aid = t2a.ID 
INNER JOIN table2 t2b ON t1.Bid = t2b.ID 
INNER JOIN table2 t2c ON t1.Cid = t2c.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC
```

Comment: SELECT t1.ID, t2a.NAME as A, t2b.NAME as B, t2c.NAME as C
from table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2a ON t1.Aid = t2a.ID 
INNER JOIN table2 t2b ON t1.Bid = t2b.ID 
INNER JOIN table2 t2c ON t1.Cid = t2c.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC

this works fine.. :)

Answer (score 1):

can you please try following query as i have manually checked it with my mysql:

```
SELECT ID,(SELECT NAME FROM table2 as t2 WHERE t1.Aid=t2.ID) as A,(SELECT NAME FROM table2 as t2 WHERE t1.Bid=t2.ID) as B,(SELECT NAME FROM table2 as t2 WHERE t1.Cid=t2.ID) as C FROM table1 AS t1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get desired results :

```
SELECT t1.ID AS ID, a.NAME AS A, b.NAME AS B, c.NAME AS C FROM (table1 t1, table2 a, table2 b, table2 c) WHERE (t1.Aid = a.ID AND t1.Bid = b.ID AND t1.Cid = c.ID) ORDER BY t1.ID;
```