# How do i display the information of foreign key instead of id in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

just like the caption, how do i fetch information from foreign key instead of id?

Here are the first table:

[image]

and here are the second table:
[image]

i want to display product_name and unit_price instead of id, how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql query with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053958/mysql-query-with-inner-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [join](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp)
Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT ft.id, pr.product_name, pr.unit_price from firsttable as ft join product as pr on ft.product_id = pr.product_id;
```

Where `firsttable` is the table of the first screenshot and `product` is the table from the second screenshot.
I don't know what you need from the first table so I just took a column `id`, however I do not know if you have this column. Here you just put whatever you need from the first table.

Comment: Well actually i need everything from first table except product_id and staff_id which product_id i need product_name and unit_price and staff_id i need staff_name.

Comment: Then after the select you write `ft.columnName` for all columns you need from the first table and `s.staff_name` for the staff name, and after the first join you do another join: `join staff as s on ft.staff_id = s.staff_id`

Comment: So if i already use SELECT * FROM firsttable so do i need to select again?

Comment: and in <td> tag, what should i code? ``` <td><?= $row['product_name']; ?></td> ``` suppose to be like this or sth?

Comment: No, you are understanding it wrong. You need to select each column individually. Not `select *` but `select ft.income_id, ft.date_income,...., pr.product_name, pr.unit_price, s.staff_name from firsttable as ft` and then you do the joins.

Comment: `$row['product_name']` should work

Comment: oh i see. thank you so much. let me redo first